# Scala List Class error

Tags: scala

i am trying to implement a class , what could be the error ? i want to implement a list of tracks as children.

It has to look like this ;

```
        id: "node37",
                name: "3.7",
                data: {},
                children:[]



class Track(id:String,name:String,data:String,Children:List[Track])
{
  def toxml=          
          <id>{id}</id>
          <name>{name}</name>
          <data>{data}</data>
          <children>{ List[Track]}</children>


}
```

Comment: What **could** be the error?  What is the problem you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make empty list use either `List.empty[Track]` or `List[Track]()`. `List[Track]` represents list class, not instance.

Comment: Or `Nil` that represents an empty `List[Nothing]`.